# Sqlite android update query not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here My update database table methods

```
public void insertionchallanval(ArrayList<String> itemcode,ArrayList<String>   item,ArrayList<String> quantity,
        ArrayList<String> date,ArrayList<String> status,ArrayList<String> id)
{
    ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0;i<status.size();i++)
    {
        if(!retriveidstatus(id.get(i)))
        {
            insertValues.put("id", id.get(i));
            insertValues.put("itemcode", itemcode.get(i));
            insertValues.put("item", item.get(i));

            insertValues.put("status", status.get(i));
            insertValues.put("date", date.get(i));
            insertValues.put("quantity", quantity.get(i));
            //insertValues.put("category", category.get(i));
            myDataBase.insert("create_challan", null, insertValues);
        }
        else
        {
            insertValues.put("id", id.get(i));
            insertValues.put("itemcode", itemcode.get(i));
            insertValues.put("item", item.get(i));
            insertValues.put("quantity", quantity.get(i));
            insertValues.put("status", status.get(i));
            insertValues.put("date", date.get(i));
            //insertValues.put("category", category.get(i));
            myDataBase.update("create_challan", insertValues, "id="+"'"+id.get(i)+"'",null );


        }  
    }
}
```

Here my check Id Methods

```
public boolean retriveidstatus(String id)
    {
        Cursor curCalllog = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM  create_challan", null);
         if(curCalllog.moveToNext() && curCalllog != null) {
             while(!curCalllog.isAfterLast())
             {
                 if(id.contains(curCalllog.getString(0)))
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
                 curCalllog.moveToNext();
             }
         }

        return false;
    }
```

Table Structure

```
id        String
status    String
date      String
challanno String
itemcode  String
item      String
quantity  String
```

When i call methods for insertion new value then its working fine but when i call again with new updated  value then update methods return 0 means no row effected

Please Help me how i can fix this problem

Thanks IN Advance

Comment: myDataBase.update("create_challan", insertValues, "id="+id.get(i),null ); remove the quotation I think id is integer not string

Comment: you also need to provide the table schema in which you are trying to update value

Comment: @SMR i share table structure please review It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking wether the **_IDs** exist or not you can use `replace()` method of the class `SQLiteDatabase` like this :

```
myDataBase.replace("create_challan", null, insertValues);
```

hope it helps Cheers :)

Comment: @Kuldeep I dont understand please elaborate.